# Is Entity Framework a good choice for an asp.net application that has to connect to MsSql,Mysql and Oracle databases?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, oracle, entity-framework

I want to know if Entity Framework can be used to create an architecture such that the asp.net application connects to MSSql,Mysql and Oracle database just by changing the connection string. If it is possible how do I proceed with it? If not what is the next best alternative? I am working on a product that is used by different customers - some prefer MsSql, some prefer Mysql and very few prefer Oracle. This means all three databases will have identical schema.

Comment: if you want to easily change the database just by changing a connection string use FluentNhibernate, although it's possible with Entityramework but fluentnhibernate is a better choice for your situation.

Comment: FluentNHibernate is not comparable with EF, it is not an ORM. It is just a library to make configuring NHibernate easier. NHibernate is an ORM we can compare with EF and it is very mature and works with all sorts of databases.

Comment: http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/02/05/using-entity-framework-6-with-postgresql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used EF with both Oracle and SQL Server. It works really well with SQL Server and reasonably well with Oracle.

However, I wouldn't have the application talk directly to EF itself. There are bound to be subtle differences between the databases that you don't want your core application to deal with. Instead, use something like the Repository Pattern and have your app talk to a repository interface. Create a repository for each database that you can plug into your app. You can certainly use EF in your repositories to map data between the database and your domain classes; but as good practice, your application shouldn't know about your data access or database technology.

Comment: Thanks.I will defintely use Repository pattern. Just want to confirm - So if I proceed with EF, for each requirement I only have to write one method using linq to entity for all three databases and not anything database specific?

Comment: @benin101 Yes... You might want to start with one repository class and implement all your data access logic with LINQ to Entities queries in there. If you end up needing to do something specific to Oracle, you can inherit from it to make an Oracle-specific repository by overriding just the methods that are different. That way you can share as much code as possible while having the ability to work around some of the database differences.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I guess that settles it for me. I know hibernate is a good choice but I think EF will get me cleaner code and I have been thinking about trying this for a while now.

Comment: I dont know where to begin now. Leaving all the design patterns aside, how can you use the same model to connect to two types of database?

Comment: A model is just a C# class that represents an entity in your domain. Entity Framework's role is to map data in your database to/from your models. So if you have more than 1 database (and therefore possibly more than 1 DbContext), you still only have 1 set of models that your domain layer deals with. You would plug in a different repositories to connect to different databases (each will have its own underlying data access code, which can be implemented with EF).

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use entity framework 6, currently not supported by oracle. But EF 5 would work right now. I am very optimistic that oracle would provide support for ef 6 in future. I have used EF5 to connect to mysql, oracle and sql server successfully using repository pattern and unit of work pattern and running successfully in production. Read also domain driven design (domain driven pattern/table pattern) and onion architecture

Comment: Thanks a lot.I guess I have a lot to learn before jumping in. Did you have any special cases where your linq queries did not work with oracle or mysql?

Comment: There was one scenario where I was using Kendo grid and using group feature on multi columns something like that not 100% remember, was getting oracle exception otherwise so far it's been almost 8 month everthing going well. For mysql, I ran with a problem with a bool datatype and had to manually update the xml file.but seems like new version of mysql has added it

Comment: Entity framework 6 is now fully supported by oracle.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html